# Google Form Throwing Off HTML Anchors?

Tags: html, css, anchor

I am using HTML anchors as a sticky nav method. Basically there is a navigation bar at the top of the page, with links that act as anchors Sign Up would be apart of this navigation bar. You would click that link and then be navigated to the part of the page where Link Here is located. That feature was working perfectly until last night. I was messing with the code beneath the Link here area, and now when you click the Sign Up link, it does not function at all.

Beneath the Link Here  is a google form. The anchor would work perfectly with the form beneath it before, but now it only works when the form is not beneath it. Here is my code:

```
<div class="six" style="width:100%; height:760px; background-color:#CC3;"> <a name="signup">test</a>
    <center>
        <div id="signup">
            <h2> <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jeFnlQodB8a3p9ASKEwXFToRq__V1nLikNSGe07kG4E/viewform">Click here to sign up</a></h2>
        </div>
    </center>
    <center>
        <form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jeFnlQodB8a3p9ASKEwXFToRq__V1nLikNSGe07kG4E/formResponse" method="POST" id="ss-form" target="_self" onsubmit="">
            <ol style="padding-left: 0">
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="width:600px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_895763809">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">First Name
                                    <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.895763809" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_895763809" dir="auto" aria-label="First Name  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1324142096">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Last Name
                                    <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.1324142096" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1324142096" dir="auto" aria-label="Last Name  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="width:600px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1845263384">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Institution or Company
                                    <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.1845263384" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1845263384" dir="auto" aria-label="Institution or Company  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1207823519">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Department
                                    <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.1207823519" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1207823519" dir="auto" aria-label="Department  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="width:600px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1402374174">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Title
                                    <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.1402374174" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1402374174" dir="auto" aria-label="Title  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1494020394">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Email Address
                                    <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.1494020394" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1494020394" dir="auto" aria-label="Email Address  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="width:600px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_225770855">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Street Address Line 1
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.225770855" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_225770855" dir="auto" aria-label="Street Address Line 1  " title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1499340779">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Street Address Line 2
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.1499340779" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1499340779" dir="auto" aria-label="Street Address Line 2  " title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="width:600px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_985725457">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">City
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.985725457" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_985725457" dir="auto" aria-label="City  " title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_628445851">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">State
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.628445851" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_628445851" dir="auto" aria-label="State  " title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="width:600px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_830119639">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Zip Code
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.830119639" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_830119639" dir="auto" aria-label="Zip Code  " title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_103516573">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Phone Number
                                    <label for="itemView.getDomIdToLabel()" aria-label="(Required field)"></label>
                                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk">*</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.103516573" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_103516573" dir="auto" aria-label="Phone Number  " aria-required="true" required="" title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="margin-left:98px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1931785670">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Twitter Handle
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" name="entry.1931785670" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_1931785670" dir="auto" aria-label="Twitter Handle  " title="">
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="width:300px; margin-left:600px; margin-top:20px;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-radio">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_1262089105">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">How did you hear about the Seminar?
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>

                            <ul class="ss-choices" role="radiogroup" aria-label="How did you hear about the Seminar?  ">
                                <li class="ss-choice-item">
                                    <label><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.875862958" value="University Contact" id="group_875862958_1" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="University Contact" ></span>
                                        <span class="ss-choice-label" style="margin-right:50px;">University Contact</span>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                                <li class="ss-choice-item">
                                    <label><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.875862958" value="Aruba Contact" id="group_875862958_2" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="Aruba Contact"></span>
                                        <span class="ss-choice-label" style="margin-right:50px;">Aruba Contact</span>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                                <li class="ss-choice-item">
                                    <label><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.875862958" value="Brocade Contact" id="group_875862958_3" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="Brocade Contact"></span>
                                        <span class="ss-choice-label" style="margin-right:50px;">Brocade Contact</span>
                                    </label>
                                </li>
                                <li class="ss-choice-item" style="margin-right:50px;">
                                    <label><span class="ss-choice-item-control goog-inline-block"><input type="radio" name="entry.875862958" value="Other" id="group_875862958_4" role="radio" class="ss-q-radio" aria-label="Other"></span>
                                        <span class="ss-choice-label">Other</span>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" style="margin-left:115px; margin-top:-90px; float:left;">
                    <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item  ss-paragraph-text">
                        <div class="ss-form-entry">
                            <label aria-hidden="true" class="ss-q-item-label aria-todo" for="entry_802038510">
                                <div class="ss-q-title">Is there a topic on the Agenda that you are most
                                    <br/>interested in hearing about?
                                </div>
                                <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                            </label>
                            <textarea name="entry.802038510" rows="10" cols="50" class="ss-q-long" id="entry_802038510" dir="auto" aria-label="Is there a topic on the Agenda that you are most interested in hearing about?  "></textarea>
                            <div class="error-message"></div>
                            <div class="required-message"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="draftResponse" value="[,,&quot;3761447958269286719&quot;]
">
                <input type="hidden" name="pageHistory" value="0">

                <input type="hidden" name="fbzx" value="3761447958269286719">

                <div class="ss-item ss-navigate">
                    <table id="navigation-table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="ss-form-entry goog-inline-block" id="navigation-buttons" dir="ltr" style="width:0px;">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit" style="margin-left:115px; width:300px; height: 50px; margin-top:0px; float:right; margin-top:50px;">
                </div>
</div>
</div>
</center>

<div id="docs-aria-speakable" class="docs-a11y-ariascreenreader-speakable docs-offscreen" aria-live="assertive" role="region" aria-atomic></div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/static/forms/client/js/2116918858-formviewer_prd.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    H5F.setup(document.getElementById('ss-form'));
    _initFormViewer(
        "[100,\x22#ccc\x22,[]\n]\n");
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Organise your code before asking maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your `<a name...` to `<a id...`. `name` is no longer supported, but may still work.
2. You have a link anchor with the name "signup" and a div tag with the name "signup". Due to the naming clash, the link is unaware of which anchor to go to. I recommend changing the link anchor to `<a id="signupAnchor">` or similar.